# Question about Ordering in Probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am just learning probability and had the following two questions:

1. Given a general equation like:

   ```
   G ⊥ L | D,I
   ```

   how do we 'read' and 'solve' it?
2. Also, is the following equation correct:

   ```
   P(A,B,C) = P(A|B) P(B|C) P(C) = P(C|B) P(B|A) P(A)?
   ```

   If no, then how do we understand the correct way to factorize it?

Thanks!

Comment: LoL.  Looks like every question asked here first comes with a downvote (without bothering for any explanation!).

Comment: The second statement is known as the [Chain Rule for Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_(probability)).  I don't understand what the first question is asking (none of the terms are defined and there does not appear to be an equation here).

Comment: @lulu, thank you for your comment.  So, is my chain rule correct - can it be interpreted in both the ways?  Besides, for the first question, those are just random variables - what I really wish to know is the order in which we should process them.  So, like does it mean that `G` and `L` are conditionally independent give `D` and `I` (or just `D`; and then what about `I`)?

Comment: Yes, both versions are correct applications of the standard chain rule.  I wouldn't write an expression of the form you are using in the first part, and I am not sure what anyone might intend by it.  If I had to guess, it would mean that $G, L$ are independent if both $D,I$ hold.  But, as I say, I have never seen any expression like that.

Comment: Correction:  I read your formulas in $b$ too quickly and assumed you were applying the chain rule correctly.   As stated, those formulas don't generally hold.  Look up the link I gave to get correct statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Given a general equation like:
>
>    G ⊥ L | D,I
>
>    how do we 'read' and 'solve' it?

There is nothing to solve.   It is the statement that "G and L are conditionally independent when given both D and I."   These literals are usually random variables, but it may also be applied to events.

$$\def\P{\operatorname{\mathsf P}} {\P(G{\in}\mathrm A,L{\in}\mathrm B\mid D{\in}\Delta,I{\in}\Gamma)} ~=~ {\P(G{\in}\mathrm A\mid D{\in}\Delta,I{\in}\Gamma)\,\P(L{\in}\mathrm B\mid D{\in}\Delta,I{\in}\Gamma)}$$

$${\P(G,L\mid D,I)} ~=~ {\P(G\mid D,I)\,\P(L\mid D,I)}$$

$\\~\\$

For some further reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence

---

> 2. Also, is the following equation correct:
>
>    $P(A,B,C) = P(A|B) P(B|C) P(C) = P(C|B) P(B|A) P(A)$?
>
> If no, then how do we understand the correct way to factorize it?

Generally the chain is:
       $\P(A,B,C) {= \P(A\mid B,C) \P(B\mid C) \P(C) \\= \P(C\mid A,B) \P(B\mid A) \P(A)\\=\P(B\mid A,C)\P(A\mid C)\P(C)\\=\text{et cetera}}$

If the expression you gave *does* apply to a *specific* scenario, it would [mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence#Rules_of_conditional_independence) that $A\perp B\mid C$ and $B\perp C\mid A$.   Which is so iff $B\perp A,C$.

Which you now can read as "A and B are conditionally independent when given C", "B and C are conditionally independent when given A", and "B and the conjunction of A,C are independent."

Comment: A more thoughtful answer than mine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It does clear up some stuff for me.  Appreciate it!  One qq though - how did you get `(C∣A,B)(B∣A)(A)`?  Can I instead write: `(C∣A,B)(A∣B)(B)`?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.  That is why I said "et cetera". $${\P(A,B,C)~}{= \P(C\mid A,B)\P(A,B) = \P(C\mid A,B)\P(A\mid B)\P(B)=\P(C\mid A,B)\P(B\mid A)\P(A)\\ = \P(B\mid A,C)\P(A,C) = \P(B\mid A,C)\P(A\mid C)\P(C)=\P(B\mid A,C)\P(C\mid A)\P(A)\\= \P(A\mid B,C)\P(B,C) = \P(A\mid B,C)\P(B\mid C)\P(C)=\P(A\mid B,C)\P(C\mid B)\P(B)}$$

Answer (score 0):

No, (2) is not correct in general.  Here is a counterexample.  Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are iid, with $P(X=1)=P(X=-1)=1/3$, and $Z=XY$.  Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be the events that $X=-1,$ that $Y=-1,$ and that $Z=-1,$ respectively.  Then $P(A,B,C)=0$ but all probabilities like $P(A)$ or $P(B|C)$ are equal to $1/2$.

The correct factorization formula is $$
P(A,B,C)=P(A)P(B|A)P(C|A,B)$$
and the 5 other versions gotten by permuting the order of conditioning.

Comment: (b) is not *generally* correct, but *may* be so in a specific scenario.